# simple search not including some channels in results

Tags: simple-search, multiple-channels

For some reason news does not get included in the search results on this site, apparently it never did and people didn't notice until a year or so later.

This is the search code

```
{exp:search:simple_form 
  channel="pages" 
  result_page="Main/search_{embed:lang}" 
  search_in="everywhere" 
  channel="pages|jobs|slides|powerpoints|events_information|events|news_and_updates|awards|student_ambassadors"
  status="not closed" 
  show_expired="yes" 
  show_future_entries="yes" 
  no_result_page="Main/search_no_results_{embed:lang}"}

    <input class="searchBox" type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" placeholder="Enter your keywords" size="18" maxlength="100" />
    <input class="searchLink" type="submit" value="search" class="submit" />

{/exp:search:simple_form}
```

Here is a screenshot of the channel names: 
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v9F2.png**

Any tips?  I've been tasked with some revisions on a EE based site.  This is the very last thing I need to fix from the very long list and its driving me bonkers, would appreciate any help! :D

Answer (score 2):

Check to ensure the fields associated with the actual channel "news_and_updates" are searchable.

In the field settings there is an option: Is field searchable?

Make sure any that need to be, are.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? Or do you need further assistance?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this post reminded me of that setting and solved my problem.

Comment: Hello sorry for late reply, just getting back to looking into this now; this does not seem to be the problem